# Selecting objects from a Custom Object

Tags: powershell

I have a custom PS Object that is something like the below:

```
ID                           Folder
MyServer01                   \\Server\Share\Share\MyServer01
MyServer02                   \\Server\Share\Share\MyServer02
```

Naturally the object itself is rather large, with over 1000 entries. I need to be able to select a specific row of the object based on querying the `ID`.

I thought something like this would work but I'm not having much luck:

```
$obj | Select-Object | Where-Object ($_.ID -eq "MyServer01")
```

I need it to return the entire row, so the above (assuming it worked) would return:

```
MyServer01                   \\Server\Share\Share\MyServer01
```

EDIT:

```
foreach ($mf in $Folders.Tables[0]) {
    $Info = New-Object System.Object
    $Info | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name ID -Value $mf.ID
    $Info | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name Folder -Value $mf.Folder
    $obj += $Info
}
```

Comment: `Select-Object` is unnecessary/redundant. What do you mean by "I'm not having much luck"? What happens?

Comment: I get no results returned.

Comment: Can you show us where `$obj` comes from? How it's assigned/created?

Comment: See edit. The $managedFolders.Tables[0] is a SQL table.

Comment: In that case your `Where-Object` filter should be just fine. Only thing that could mess with it is if the `ID` has trailing whitespace (ie `"MyServer01 "`). Try with `-match "MyServer01"` or `-like "*MyServer01*"`

Comment: Neither of those return results :|

Comment: Then there must be something wrong with how you are testing against your real data. Whitespace seems the likely culprit. Could be other hidden characters as well. You should use `.trim()` when you set the values at object creation perhaps.

Comment: It does not work even if I use "*" in the where

Comment: What does $obj.gettype() return?

Comment: Returns BaseType: System.Object and Name: PSCustomObject

Comment: If $obj was originally created as a custom object, you should be getting an error on $obj += $Info.  That should only work on an array or hash table.

Comment: Sorry - you are correct, $obj is of BaseType System.Array

Comment: I think the problem may be in your object creation.  Try adding -Passthru to those Add-Member cmdlets.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100897/discussion-between-pnp-and-mjolinor).

Answer (score 3):

Use a hashtable for storing your objects:

```
$obj = @{}
foreach ($mf in $Folders.Tables[0]) {
    $Info = New-Object -Type System.Object
    $Info | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name ID -Value $mf.ID
    $Info | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name Folder -Value $mf.Folder
    $obj[$mf.ID] = $Info
}
```

Don't append to an array in a loop, as that tends to perform poorly.

If your code doesn't depend on the objects being created explicitly as `System.Object` I'd also recommend to create them as custom objects:

```
$obj = @{}
foreach ($mf in $Folders.Tables[0]) {
    $Info = New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property @{
      'ID'     = $mf.ID
      'Folder' = $mf.Folder
    }
    $obj[$mf.ID] = $Info
}
```

Comment: +1 for `New-Object -Property @{}` over `Add-Member`, but the real overhead comes from continually resizing the array with `+=`. Assigning the entire `foreach` loop directly to the array variable (`$obj = foreach(){}`) will exhibit the same performance improvement as with a hashtable, with the added advantage that you don't need a distinct identifier per object